# Python failing IF STATEMENTS/ Changing Variables

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm having an issue. Speedy responses would be greatly appreciated! My program is failing IF conditions becuase my functions are not changing the global variable properly for me. They're supposed to, for example, be able to go south and take a key. With that key they can go East and open a locked drawer. Except... they fail the if check to be able to open the drawer.

Thanks in advance! The code blocks in question should be below!

```
def south():
    print ("You can see a key just lying there on the table! What luck!")
    choice = raw_input("You better TAKE that!")
    if choice == 'TAKE' :
        print "You took the key!"
        return Key1 == 1, moverooms()
    else:
        print "You didn't take the key to freedom!?"
        south()


def east():
    print("You can see a drawer here! Wonder what is inside?")
    choice = raw_input("You can MOVEROOMS, or try to USE the drawer and TAKE what's inside...\n ")
    if choice == 'USE' :
        print "You try to open the drawer... \n"
        if Key1 == 1 :
            print "You use the key to open the drawer and find a flashlight inside! Better TAKE it!"
            Drawer == 1
            east()

    else:
        print ("It's locked! Better find a key...\n")
        east()
```

Comment: What is the point of `return Key1 == 1, moverooms()`? I can almost guarantee you that line is not doing what you think it does

Comment: I'm new to python and programming in general; I put that line in there in one of my many attempts to fix this before finally giving up and posting on stack.

Comment: You don't have any global variables. Which variable do you think is global?

Comment: In addition to not having any global variables, you aren't setting any variables. (Except `choice`)

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to use global variables, but if you must, your problem seems to be that you're not assigning `Key1 = 1` in your `TAKE` conditional, but returning `True` or `False` according to whether or not it already has that value (`Key1==1`). Note that you need to set it before the `return`.

Note that if you want to do this (you don't), you'll need to assert `global Key` at the top of your `south()` function.

To avoid global variables, return a value for `Key1` from `south` and pass it to `east`:

```
def south():
    print ("You can see a key just lying there on the table! What luck!")
    choice = raw_input("You better TAKE that!")
    if choice == 'TAKE' :
        print "You took the key!"
        Key1 = 1
    else:
        print "You didn't take the key to freedom!?"
        Key1 = 0
    return Key1

def east(Key1):
    print("You can see a drawer here! Wonder what is inside?")
    choice = raw_input("You can MOVEROOMS, or try to USE the drawer and TAKE what's inside...\n ")
    if choice == 'USE' :
        print "You try to open the drawer... \n"
        if Key1 == 1 :
            print "You use the key to open the drawer and find a flashlight inside! Better TAKE it!"
            Drawer = 1
            return Drawer
    else:
        print ("It's locked! Better find a key...\n")
        Drawer = 0
    return Drawer
```

You'll have to handle the logic of the calls to `south` and `east` yourself, though.

Comment: Hey there, I only changed it ==1 because it was giving me a syntax error otherwise. I'm a bit of a novice; how do I use variables that aren't 'global' and initiliazed at the beginning of the program?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but ideally you'll do something along these lines:

```
class Character(object):
    """
    This class represents the player.
    It keeps track of found items, opened drawers, etc...
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # game start: Key not found, drawer not opened.
        self.has_key= False
        self.has_opened_drawer= False

    def go_south(self):
        print "You can see a key just lying there on the table! What luck!"
        choice = raw_input("You better TAKE that!\n")
        if choice == 'TAKE' :
            print "You took the key!"
            self.has_key= True
        else:
            print "You didn't take the key to freedom!?"

    def go_east(self):
        print "You can see a drawer here! Wonder what is inside?"
        choice = raw_input("You can MOVEROOMS, or try to USE the drawer and TAKE what's inside...\n")
        if choice == 'USE':
            print "You try to open the drawer... \n"
            if self.has_key:
                print "You use the key to open the drawer and find a flashlight inside! Better TAKE it!"
                self.has_opened_drawer= True
        else:
            print "It's locked! Better find a key...\n"

    def input_loop(self):
        while True:
            choice= raw_input('Do you want to go SOUTH or EAST?\n')
            if choice=='SOUTH':
                self.go_south()
            elif choice=='EAST':
                self.go_east()

player= Character() # create a Character
player.input_loop() # and let the user control it
```

Instead of using global variables, you create a `Character` to store all necessary data, like whether the key was found, or whether the drawer has been opened. That way you won't clutter your global scope with variables.